# How to get columns names during a SELECT operation that returns zero items in SQLite

Tags: c++, sql, sqlite

I'm calling

```
sqlite3_exec(db, "SELECT a,b,Z FROM t1 WHERE t1.id = 1", func_ptr, arg_ptr)
```

to collect the row content and the column names. I'm trying to create a generic helper function that will take any SELECT command and construct a `vector<vector<string>>` with the first row containing the column names (and rest containing the contents of the rows).

But this fails to capture the column names when there are no rows to show since `func_ptr` is only called with one or more rows to display.

How can I get the column names when `SELECT` returns zero rows?
EDIT:  I would prefer not to create a level of indirection by creating a table and then calling `SELECT` on that table. Thanks.
EDIT:  I would only like to collect what the `SELECT` statement contains.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`PRAGMA table_info(tablename);`](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_table_info) to get a result set that includes column name and type for the given table.

Call the pragma as you would a normal query (i.e. with `sqlite3_exec` for instance).

If you need this information for a SQL statement you didn't generate yourself that contains a column selection, you need to use a prepared statement (you should be doing that anyway). Then you can use `sqlite3_column_count` and `sqlite3_column_name` to get the information you're after.

Example usage:

```
sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, "select a,b from t where 0=1", -1, &stmt, 0);
if( rc!=SQLITE_OK ){
    fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", zErrMsg);
    sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
}

int cols = sqlite3_column_count(stmt);
fprintf(stdout, "%d columns\n", cols);
for (int i=0; i<cols; i++)
    fprintf(stdout, "%d. %s\n", i, sqlite3_column_name(stmt, i));

// iterate over the results with sqlite3_step
// dispose of the statement with sqlite3_finalize
```

You can adapt this to store the column names in a `std::vector`.

Comment: Does this mean I have to create a table first? E.g.
    CREATE TABLE tablename AS SELECT ...

Comment: No, you use `pragma table_info(t1)` in your example, you don't need to create anything more.

Comment: Sorry, not a clear question.  How about I use SELECT a,b,z FROM t1... That is the SELECT command describes only the columns I'm interested in, so the pragma table_info(t1) would return all column names and not what's in the custom SELECT command. thanks.

Comment: You changed your question and now it makes no sense - you already know the column names in your second form.

Comment: I should have made it clearer. Sorry. Your answer is the best idea so far for my ambiguous original question :)  I'm trying to create a  generic function that will construct a vector<vector<string>> with the first row containing the column names.

Comment: thank you! that's helpful.  I guess it's time for me to upgrade my sqlite knowledge :)